# Timeout on remote query over database link

Tags: oracle-10g, remote

We are trying to verify if a database link is up before inserting data into a remote database.  We have no control over the remote database's behavior and status.  We need to set a timeout on a query which is using a database link before deciding whether we can insert data.

Currently when the link or the remote database goes down in the middle of a transaction, the user has to wait for up to 20 minutes before regaining control on the session.  We want to set the limit to a minute or less.

We're running Oracle 10gR2.

How can we set a timeout for a query like this?

Comment: Do you mean it times out whilst doing the `INSERT`, or are you pulling data from the remote DB before inserting back? Can you edit your question with a timeline of the local<>remote behaviour please? Are you building some kind of staging table that can be persisted locally before inserting? Checking if the remote DB is up is as simple as `SELECT 'UP' from DUAL@REMOTEDB`. I suspect this is firewall timeout issues anyway :) (Normally is)